# Preventing site from refreshing using JS

Tags: javascript, browser

Some websites have the annoying quality of auto-refreshing using some JS magic. This seems to bypass the browser's "do not auto refresh" options.

My question - is there a simple way of telling the browser (also via JS, in an add-on) "do not listen to them! Never auto-refresh!"?

EDIT: Just to make myself clear - I want to write a browser extension that prevents the current page from giving a "refresh" signal - whether auto-refresh or "standard" refresh given automatically by the page using some timer. I think that's a standard JS question...

Comment: This would be a better question for SuperUser or a similar site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: **Sorry, I missunderstood the question!**

I think that what you need is this:

```
window.onkeypress = window.onkeyup = window.onkeydown = function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // or, in this case: 
    //return false;
};
```

When the window will receive the events of keypress, keyup e keydown signals that the default behavior MUST be prevented. If you return false, you will stop the event chain, preventing to execute anything too. The two lines have the same effect, give a try commenting each line.

Here is a improoved example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Testing...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="clickDiv">Click me ;)</div>
        <br/>
        <input id="typeInput" value="Type something ! (here)"/>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onkeypress = window.onkeyup = window.onkeydown = function( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            };
            document.getElementById( "clickDiv" ).onclick = function( event ) { 
                 console.log( "you clicked me and the window events related to the keyboard are still being prevented ;)" );
            };
            document.getElementById( "typeInput" ).onkeyup = function( event ) { 
                 console.log( "you typed inside me and the window events related to the keyboard are still being prevented ;)" );
            };
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: This is an "override" in a sense (like overloading a + operator in C++) - I don't see how it will be able to prevent an "auto-refresh". Got code :) ?

Comment: @DaneBalia: I missundertood the question... Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

All popular browsers except Chrome and Safari already have options related to disabling auto-refreshing. To disable auto-refreshing in these browsers, check out this article: http://maketecheasier.com/disable-web-page-auto-refresh-for-various-browsers/2010/12/12

For a Chrome extension to stopping auto-refresh, check this out: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lcldcllmbokpbniijpnkpgoboadbfphb

Comment: I've already read the first link. Problem is, it's not working against some JS-bases auto refreshings (which are not "pure" auto-refreshing; just the JS telling the browser to refresh).

Answer (score -1):

Each browser can have this functionality [turned off](http://maketecheasier.com/disable-web-page-auto-refresh-for-various-browsers/2010/12/12) but I don't think there is a way to affect these changes through JS unless you write an "Extension".

Comment: Chrome and Safari don't have the option to turn off this functionality.

Comment: Correct! Will bump you on this, I see you answered before me.